# How can I get a mongo subset of a collection based on an another collection

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections.

Collection 1 is like an account.
Collection 2 creates a unique association between a user and an account

I am trying to return the accounts for which the user has no association

Collection1 schema

```
const Collection1Schema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

Collection1 data

```
[
  {
    "_id": "61cf8452fca008360872c9cd",
    "name": "Aff 2"
  },
  {
    "_id": "61cf845ffca008360872c9d0",
    "name": "AFF 1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "61cf8468fca008360872c9d3",
    "name": "Aff 3"
  }
]
```

Collection2 schema

```
const Collection2Schema = new Schema({
  userID: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
  col_1_ID: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
});
```

Collection2 data

```
[
  {
    "_id": "61e05bb5fe1d8327d4c73663",
    "userID": "61cf82dac828bd519cfd38ca",
    "col_1_ID": "61cf845ffca008360872c9d0"
  },
  {
    "_id": "61e05c14fe1d8327d4c7367d",
    "userID": "61cf82dac828bd519cfd38ca",
    "col_1_ID": "61cf8468fca008360872c9d3"
  },
  {
    "_id": "61e05ca0fe1d8327d4c73695",
    "userID": "61e05906246ccc41d4ebd30f",
    "col_1_ID": "61cf8452fca008360872c9cd"
  }
]
```

This is what I have so far... but it does not return what the user is NOT apart of

I am using Collection2 as the basis in the pipeline

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'userID': new ObjectId('61cf82dac828bd519cfd38ca')
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'Collection1', 
      'localField': 'col_1_ID', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'aa'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$aa', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }
]
```

What I would like to return is all the **collection 1 documents** ( where userIdD = '61cf82dac828bd519cfd38ca') is NOT associated in collection 2 ... like this :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "61cf8452fca008360872c9cd",
    "name": "Aff 2"
  }
]
```

**UPDATE 1**
Here is a playground where *another user has joined another account*, so the pipeline does not return "Aff 2" like expected

https://mongoplayground.net/p/W6W88_2MaI3

**UPDATE 2**
Here is a playground that almost does what I want... it's returning duplication "AFF 2" entries.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/nTI3MKNPEmD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER:**

after messing around with several mongo playgrounds and digging into a few different pipeline attributes... here is what works:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/xbZeRfVcrZq

Data:

```
db={
  "Collection1": [
    {
      "_id": "61cf8452fca008360872c9cd",
      "name": "Aff 2"
    },
    {
      "_id": "61cf845ffca008360872c9d0",
      "name": "AFF 1"
    },
    {
      "_id": "61cf8468fca008360872c9d3",
      "name": "Aff 3"
    }
  ],
  "Collection2": [
    {
      "_id": "61e05bb5fe1d8327d4c73663",
      "userID": "61cf82dac828bd519cfd38ca",
      "col_1_ID": "61cf845ffca008360872c9d0"
    },
    {
      "_id": "61e05c14fe1d8327d4c7367d",
      "userID": "61cf82dac828bd519cfd38ca",
      "col_1_ID": "61cf8468fca008360872c9d3"
    },
    {
      "_id": "61e05ca0fe1d8327d4c73695",
      "userID": "61e05906246ccc41d4ebd30f",
      "col_1_ID": "61cf8452fca008360872c9cd"
    },
    {
      "_id": "61e05c14fe1d8327d4c73600",
      "userID": "61cf82dac828bd519cfd3111",
      "col_1_ID": "61cf8468fca008360872c9d3"
    },
    {
      "_id": "61e05c14fe1d8327d4c73601",
      "userID": "61cf82dac828bd519cfd3112",
      "col_1_ID": "61cf8452fca008360872c9cd"
    },
    
  ]
}
```

Pipeline:

```
db.Collection1.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Collection2",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "col_1_ID",
      "as": "joined_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "joined_docs.userID": {
        $ne: "61cf82dac828bd519cfd38ca"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      "path": "$joined_docs",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      "name": {
        "$first": "$name"
      },
      
    }
  }
])
```

result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "61cf8452fca008360872c9cd",
    "name": "Aff 2"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

try the inversing lookup

https://mongoplayground.net/p/hXAYyv8X461

```
db.Collection1.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Collection2",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "col_1_ID",
      "as": "joined_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      "path": "$joined_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "joined_docs.userID": {
        $ne: "61cf82dac828bd519cfd38ca"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "joined_docs": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Glad that worked :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1211547/indybee  :  whoops... not quite ... when I started adding users to other accounts the query returns wrong results - I have updated my question

Comment: another try in a new answer, if that works I will delete this one from the post

Comment: I just noticed you found what you need in your latest post, glad you got it working

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/HDm2sbdvH88

```
db.Collection1.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Collection2",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "col_1_ID",
      "as": "joined_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      "path": "$joined_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        account_id: "$_id",
        account_name: "$name",
        
      },
      user_ids: {
        $push: {
          "userID": "$joined_docs.userID"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "user_ids.userID": {
        $nin: [
          "61cf82dac828bd519cfd38ca"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      user_ids: 0
    }
  }
])
```